# Checking if nested attribute exists

Tags: python, python-2.7, data-structures

I have a nested `OrderedDict` that I want to extract a value out of.  But before I can extract that value I have to make sure a long chain of attributes exist and that their values aren't none.

What is the most pythonic way of improving the following code:

```
if 'first' in data and \
    data['first'] and \
    'second' in data['first'] and \
    data['first']['second'] and \
    'third' in data['first']['second'] and \
    data['first']['second']['third']:
    x = data['first']['second']['third']
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another route would be to use the `get()` method:

```
x = data.get('first', {}).get('second', {}).get('third', None)
```

If at any point the key does not exist, then `x = None`

Comment: this won't work if one of the fields is set to None. e.g. `data = {'first': {'second': None}}
`

Answer (score 3):

You could surround it in a try/except block like so:

```
try:
    x = data['first']['second']['third']
    assert x
except KeyError, AssertionError:
    pass
```

Comment: `assert` shouldn't be used here

Comment: Well he wanted to make sure the value isn't None, hence the reason it's there.

Comment: Would I need another try catch block for each additional assignment?  E.g. `x=data['a']` and `y=data['b']`.

Comment: Only if you're uncertain 'a' and 'b' are keys in data.

Comment: `assert x` has no role here. `if x is None: raise ValueError()` would be the proper way.